# Table Storage: Retrieve all partition keys

Tags: azure-table-storage

Is it possible to retrieve all partition keys with a Azure storage table without traversing through all the data in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. A full table scan is required for retrieving all partition keys with Azure storage Table. However to reduce the data transferred you can project only the PKs.